# Displaying HTML code from WYSIWYG in React gives me a warning

Tags: reactjs, html-parsing

In this React application I have a WYSIWYG component that saves HTML code. The code is persisted in the database. I display the code like this:

```
import ReactHtmlParser from "react-html-parser";

...

<div className="card-body pt-4">
  {ReactHtmlParser(props.project.description)}
</div>
```

React does not like it and says:

> Warning: A component is `contentEditable` and contains `children`
> managed by React. It is now your responsibility to guarantee that none
> of those nodes are unexpectedly modified or duplicated. This is
> probably not intentional.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely using `contentEditable` in `props.project.description`. This raises such a warning. It arises because the `contentEditable` attribute makes it possible to change the content inside this element and these changes are not controlled by React.

Therefore, you have three options.

- Don't use the contentEditable attribute
- Ignore this warning
- Tell React explicitly that you're aware of this `contentEditable` behavior and don't need these notifications.

For third option, use [suppressContentEditableWarning](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#suppresscontenteditablewarning)

Comment: the code actually does not have contenteditable="true", I checked. I also added the suppress option <div className = "card-body pt-4" suppressContentEditableWarning={true}>
        {ReactHtmlParser(props.project.description)}
       </div> . the warning didn't go away

Comment: @usertest, then your problem may not be in this part of the code. Try to find the `contenteditable` attribute in the resulting DOM through the developer tools in your browser.